# How to solve this logarithmic equation $\ln(x/C_1)+C_2/x=C_1/C_2$

Tags: logarithms, lambert-w, transcendental-equations

I have this equation which represents two intersection points of a graph with a line. Can anyone help me please to solve it for $x$?

$C_1$, $C_2$ are constants. $x$ is a variable. The first solution is $x=C_1$, but I am looking for the other one please.

$$
\ln⁡(\frac{x}{C_1} )+ \frac{C_2}{x}=\frac{C_2}{C_1} 
$$
Many thanks.

Comment: I don't think that there is a general expression for the solution. For $C_1 > C_2$,  there are two solutions that can be found.

Comment: How is $x=C_1$ a solution?

Comment: Sorry I had a mistake in the fraction, can please check now?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\ln{\left(\frac{x}{C_1}\right)}+\frac{C_2}{x}=\frac{C_1}{C_2}
&\iff\frac{x}{C_1}\exp{\left(\frac{C_2}{x}\right)}=\exp{\left(\frac{C_1}{C_2}\right)}\\
&\iff\frac{C_1}{x}\exp{\left(-\frac{C_2}{x}\right)}=\exp{\left(-\frac{C_1}{C_2}\right)}\\
&\iff-\frac{C_2}{x}\exp{\left(-\frac{C_2}{x}\right)}=-\frac{C_2}{C_1}\exp{\left(-\frac{C_1}{C_2}\right)}\\
&\iff-\frac{C_2}{x}=W_k\left(-\frac{C_2}{C_1}\exp{\left(-\frac{C_1}{C_2}\right)}\right)\\
&\iff x=-\frac{C_2}{W_k\left(-\frac{C_2}{C_1}\exp{\left(-\frac{C_1}{C_2}\right)}\right)}\\
\end{align}
where $W_k(z)$ denotes the $k$th branch of the Lambert-W function. Here I am assuming the principal branch of the complex natural logarithm.

Comment: Dear Peter, Appologies that there was a mistake in the fraction (C1/C2)
It becomes C2/C1
Can you please check now if the solution is changed
what is Lambert -W function 
I would be greatful if you can refer a mathbook that I can read
Many thanks